# How to disable backface-culling?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to create a mesh with faces that are semitransparent in such a manner that I can see the back faces through the front faces.

Setting the transparency of the material allowed me to see a completely different mesh if it were behind the "transparent" mesh, but it didn't allow me to see through to its own faces.

The mesh as a whole got transparent, but the faces all kept an opaque appearance (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles? I'm guessing BI.. This is caused by backface culling.

Comment: Or possibly Blender Game Engine? Then you will not only have to deal with backface culling, but also with the rendering order of the triangles.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10838/599

Comment: I assume BI as well. I'm intending to pull the models into SceneKit (iOS) so I'm not sure if cycles will work, but I'll give it a try! I'll try your approach tonight. Thank you!

Comment: @RyJ I don't know anything about scenekit, but I'm guessing you will have to set up the shading outside of blender. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9215/599.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simplified version of the node setup from my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10838/599), you can do this with cycles (click on the image to get a bigger version):

[image]

Comment: In an unrelated question: How do you get to this tree view? The upper portion of your image?

Comment: @RyJ This is Node Editor accessible from each window menu (left icon).