# How can I make the outside of a sphere transparent

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency

I want to make the outside of a sphere transparent so that when I'm looking at it, all I see is the inside of the opposite face. If I'm close enough to the sphere that I can only see a small section of the outside then I want to look through that section and see the majority of the inside of the sphere. To do this I just need to make it so the sphere is transparent when viewed from the outside but that the inside face is visible.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10836/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the technique from [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10838/599), but with just a transparent shader for the "outside" material:

[image]

This setup makes the frontsides of faces invisible to [*camera rays*](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html#ray-visibility) and the backsides of faces invisible to non camera rays.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Like enabling X-ray display but for the render. *BTW how did you get your nodes to show only the label and output of the connected node?* For example, even when I minimize my Light Path node I still see 10 outputs but none of them are labeled "Is Camera Ray" like yours is. Is that an add-on, a preference, or a newer Blender build than I have?

Comment: @Mentalist You can hide unused sockets with `Ctrl H`

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks! That will help me slim down my node setups a lot!